# How to parse a web page that has login and password to enter in to view user's personal page? (iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parsing

How do I parse a webpage with login and password requirements to view the individual user's information, like facebook for example. I want my app to access to the individual facebook page, after entering login and password in the app.

By now I was able to parse usual webpages with TFHpple, but I have no idea how to pass the login and password requirements to get the page content.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the process for logging in is:

User POSTs data to a login form with username and password.
The server responds with a session cookie
Future requests include the session cookie and the server knows that the user is authenticated.

If you wan to do this login process on your user's behalf through our app, you'll need to save the cookies and send them on subsequent requests.

Comment: I think NSHTTPCookieStorage is what you need to use: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks. but concerning POSTing login and password to the server, is this right a right way to do it?

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"xxx", @"password": @"xx"};
    [manager POST:@"webpage" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

        NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
        
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Facebook iOS SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

I think it's a little bit strange from the architecture perspective that you want to parse the personal Facebook newsfeed, when there's the possibility to get the data via the Facebook API (given that you have the appropriate User Permission)...

Comment: actually it's not facebook that I want to parse. I just used it as an example to make it easier to explain what i wanted to do